# Recursive sorting method not stopping at the base case

Tags: java

For school, I am trying to write a recursive sorting algorithm. Yet for some reason it is not stopping at the base case and help would be greatly appreciated. The error is

> java.lang.StackOverflowError

Here is the method:

```
 public static List recursiveMergeSort(List<Integer> list1){
    List<Integer> list = list1;
    List<Integer> listR = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Integer> listL = new ArrayList<>();


     int counter =0;

    if(list.size() == 1){
        return list;
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i <list.size()/2-1; i++){
            listL.add(list.get(i));
        }

        for(int i = list.size()/2; i  < list.size()-1; i++) {
            listR.add(list.get(i));
        }

        recursiveMergeSort(listL);
        recursiveMergeSort(listR);

        list = merge(listL, listR);
        counter++;
    }
    return (list);
}

public static List merge(List<Integer> listL, List<Integer> listR){
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int listIndex = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(leftIndex < listL.size() && rightIndex < listR.size()){
        if(listL.get(leftIndex) <= listR.get(leftIndex)){
            listR.add(listIndex, listL.get(leftIndex));
            leftIndex = leftIndex + 1;

        }else {
            list.add(list.get(listIndex), listR.get(rightIndex));
            rightIndex = rightIndex +1;
        }
        listIndex = listIndex + 1;
    }
    if(leftIndex < listL.size()){
        copyRest(listL, leftIndex, list, listIndex);
    } else {
        copyRest(listR, rightIndex, list, listIndex);
    }
    return (list);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: At a guess, you hit a point where your list size is 0, missing the size of 1 completely. Check with a debugger (or add a test for 0)?

Comment: Even if I change the base case to <= 1 it doesn't stop.

Comment: you are discarding the result of `merge(listL, listR)`.. you probably want to do `list = merge(listL, listR);`? hard to say without seeing the full code, including the `merge()` method and `listL` `listR` declarations

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't notice the two sub-lists weren't local; could mean every call is just adding to the already existing lists ad infinitum

Comment: Still, after moving the sublists into the method, and after changing list to 
`list = merge(listL, listR)`

Comment: showing the deceleration of listL and ListR would help. you know you can edit your question.

Comment: @AbdulRabMemon What do you mean by deceleration?

Comment: he means 'declaration'

Comment: @JonathanZier please update your question with a [verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code

Comment: I suggest updating the code to include the changes you've made, adding the merge method to it, and adding the initialization of the original list and call to the first iteration.

Comment: Ok, just updated what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the two inner for loops:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <list.size()/2-1; i++){ // should be i<list.size()/2
        listL.add(list.get(i));
    }


    for(int i = list.size()/2; i  < list.size()-1; i++) { //should be i  < list.size()
        listR.add(list.get(i));
    }
```

Initially when you give an input of size 5, listR gets two elements (elements with indices 2 and 3) and in the recursive call for listR, none of the for loops get executed, so the recursive call goes on and on until you get an error

Comment: Yes! I see it now, I was confused with the -1 because I thought it was needed for the index, yet < anyways would stop at one less than the condition. Is this correct?

Comment: @JonathanZier, yes, < will always stop at one less than the number on the right